# Rotating a text with a background color in a table

Tags: css, rotation, html-table, transform

How can you rotate a text in a table with a background color so it fills the whole cell and not just the text?

css

```
.rotate {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE6,IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* IE8 */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

html

```
<TABLE CELLPADDING=5 CELLSPACING=0>
  <TR>
    <TH>Operator</TH>
    <TH>Ext</TH>
    <TH>City</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Starflower</TD>
    <TD>8172</TD>
    <TD>San Francisco</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Melody</TD>
    <TD>5673</TD>
    <TD>San Pedro</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Symphony</TD>
    <TD>3820</TD>
    <TD>Montreal</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/orL3ky3g/)

Comment: It does fill the whole cell. You're rotating the whole cell.

Comment: When you look on the browser, colors and text overlaps (if you type something longer),and white spaces between a text and cell borders.

Comment: The first `td` elements of each row are fully yellow, the "cell borders" that you are thinking about are likely not the actual cell borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you are rotating the whole cell, and the yellow background covers the cell. Thus, it is working exactly as it should. With your code, look at where the borders are:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.rotate {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* FF3.5+ */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);
  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);
  /* IE6,IE7 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";
  /* IE8 */
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<TABLE CELLPADDING=5 CELLSPACING=0>
  <TR>
    <TH>Operator</TH>
    <TH>Ext</TH>
    <TH>City</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Starflower</TD>
    <TD>8172</TD>
    <TD>San Francisco</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Melody</TD>
    <TD>5673</TD>
    <TD>San Pedro</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">Symphony</TD>
    <TD>3820</TD>
    <TD>Montreal</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

However, what you are after may be something like this. Again, see where the actual cell borders go.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.rotate {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rotate > div {
  transform:
    translateX(45%)
    rotate(-90deg);
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<TABLE CELLPADDING=5 CELLSPACING=0>
  <TR>
    <TH>Operator</TH>
    <TH>Ext</TH>
    <TH>City</TH>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">
      <div>Starflower</div>
    </TD>
    <TD>8172</TD>
    <TD>San Francisco</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">
      <div>Melody</div>
    </TD>
    <TD>5673</TD>
    <TD>San Pedro</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD class="rotate">
      <div>Symphony</div>
    </TD>
    <TD>3820</TD>
    <TD>Montreal</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: @George Great, please accept the answer so that your question does not float around unanswered.